# Remote Kendo Auto Complete not working

Tags: knockout.js, autocomplete, kendo-ui, odata, kendo-autocomplete

I am new to kendo and was trying to implement a custom editor for a Kendo grid column, which is a kendoAutoComplete.

I was successfully able to get the data from the backend, having enabled serverFiltering to true, but ultimately  the data is not getting binded.

Here is the code:

Custom Editor Implementation:

```
$('<input class="auto-mat" data-value-field="MAT" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoAutoComplete({
                autobind: true,
                suggest: true,
                filter: "contains",
                minLength: 3,
                dataTextField: "DES",
                dataValueField: "MAT",
                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    //serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "odata",
                            url: utils.serverURL() + '&event=SEARCH&field=' + options.field,
                            data: {
                                value: function(){
                                    return $('.auto-mat .k-input').data('kendoAutoComplete').value();
                                }
                            }                                
                        }                           

                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: function (response) {                                
                            return response.data;
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
```

And the data from the backend comes in this manner:

```
{"DATA":[{"MAT":"111","DES":"COAL"},{"MAT":"222","DES":"TEXT1"}]}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean `the data is not getting binded`?  When you type in the auto complete box, nothing shows?

Comment: @Rick S yes you are absolutely right, the data doesn't show , but i see the filtered data coming correctly in the network tab...any solution??

Comment: Have you tried taking this code out of the grid and just have it be a stand alone control?  Just to see if it works on its own.  My guess is it has something to do with the binding you set up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set option.field as input name and it will be automatically binded.

Btw, you must to enable serverFiltering too. it's required for remote suggestions.

Try this one:

`$('<input class="auto-mat" data-value-field="MAT" name="'+ options.field + '"/>...`

```
...     
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your data is in an element called `DATA` (uppercase), your `schema.data` function should be:

```
data: function (response) {                                
    return response.data;
}
```

or simply:

```
data: "DATA"
```

You should also note that since you have set `minLength` to `3`, until you type `3` characters it will not send the request to the server for bringing the data.

Comment: while minLength 3 was a requirement , your suggestions couldn't help me with it....secondly i am not able to get the debugger in the schema function. Can you help me with what may be the case here?Note: I get the data perfectly , as per the question.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the `data-bind="value:..` in your element will do nothing in this case because your element is not MVVM bound.

Programatic widget initialization with `.kendoAutoComplete` and MVVM declarative initialization are very different things in Kendo, and don't really mix like this.

You probably want to use the `change` event on the autocomplete to get the value a user entered.

---

You could try something like this:

```
var _value = "Some Value";

var _autoCompleteWidget = $('<input class="auto-mat" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoAutoComplete({
            autobind: true,
            suggest: true,
            filter: "contains",
            minLength: 3,
            dataTextField: "DES",
            dataValueField: "MAT",
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                //serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "odata",
                        url: utils.serverURL() + '&event=SEARCH&field=' + options.field,
                        data: {
                            value: function(){
                                return $('.auto-mat .k-input').data('kendoAutoComplete').value();
                            }
                        }                                
                    }                           

                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (response) {                                
                        return response.data;
                    }
                }
            }),
            change: function (changeEvent) {
                _value = this.value(); // get new value from autocomplete
            }
        }).data("kendoAutoComplete");

_autoCompleteWidget.value(_value); // set initial value
```

or you could do the entire thing MVVM, which would instead be something like:

```
$('<input class="auto-mat" data-role="autocomplete" data-suggest="true" data-filter="contains" data-min-length="3" data-text-field="DES" data-value-field="MAT" data-bind="source: dataSource, value: value" />')
    .appendTo(container);

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    value: "Some Value",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                //serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "odata",
                        url: utils.serverURL() + '&event=SEARCH&field=' + options.field,
                        data: {
                            value: function(){
                                return $('.auto-mat .k-input').data('kendoAutoComplete').value();
                            }
                        }                                
                    }                           

                },
                schema: {
                    data: function (response) {                                
                        return response.data;
                    }
                }
            })
});

kendo.bind(container, viewModel);
```

---

Unless there was a `kendo.bind()` call somewhere else in your code that wasn't shown, then the `data-*` attributes on the HTML element aren't used. That means that your `data-bind="value: ..."` was not being used, which would be why your value was not updating.

Without the MVVM binding (enabled by the call to `kendo.bind()`) you need to move values around yourself, which is why I use the calls to `.value()` to get and set the values in the first code example.

Comment: I am using an mvvm declaration itself....this is the exact way we define a editor for grid column , and second part of it is if the list itself doesn't show up, whats with using the change method? Any other way you can help me out?